# How I can display concatenation of many strings with ajax? (or not)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have span with some text. I need then `<span class="switcher__result">` default is `display: none` but if my `<button class="switcher switcher__Last collapsible">` change the text, my result span is `display: block` and text of my span is concatenation text of all my `<button class="switcher switcher__Last collapsible">`

```html
<button class="switcher switcher__Last collapsible">X1</button>
<button class="switcher switcher__Last collapsible">X2</button>
<button class="switcher switcher__Last collapsible">X3</button>
<button class="switcher switcher__Last collapsible">X4</button>

<span class="switcher__result">X1 X2 X3 X4</span>
```

This script changing text from buttons.

```js
$('.collapsibleContent').find('span').click(function (e) {
        let txt = $(this).text().split('-')[0];
        $(this).parent().prev('.switcher').text(txt + '\u00A0');
    });
```

How can I make script for `<span class="switcher__result">X1 X2 X3 X4</span>`.

```html
<button class="switcher switcher__Last collapsible">X1</button>
<div class="collapsibleContent">
<span class="choise__block-item">Text</span>
<span class="choise__block-item">Text</span>
<span class="choise__block-item">Text</span>
</div>

<button class="switcher switcher__Last collapsible">X2</button>
<div class="collapsibleContent">
<span class="choise__block-item">Text</span>
<span class="choise__block-item">Text</span>
<span class="choise__block-item">Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `collapsibleContent` here? I do not see that in your HTML code.

Comment: And what is or isn't happening with the code shown?

Comment: Sorry! Im updating post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Check length for `span` text and concat your string and display result on `span` tag.

```js
$('.collapsibleContent').find('span').click(function(e) {
  let txt = $(this).text();
  $(this).parent().prev('.switcher').text(txt);
  $('.result').show();
  if ($('.result').html().length > 0) {
    txt = $('.result').text() + ', ' + txt;
    $('.result').text(txt);
  }
  $('.result').text(txt);
});
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.result {
  display: none;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="switcher collapsible">X1</button>
<div class="collapsibleContent">
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text</span>
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text2</span>
</div>
<button class="switcher collapsible">X2</button>
<div class="collapsibleContent">
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text3</span>
  <span class="choise__block-item">Text4</span>
</div>

Result:<span class='result'></span>
```

Comment: How i can made just one click? Then, if i click many times content coppied like this: Result:Text, Text3, Text, Text2, Text3, Text4, Text4, Text4, Text4, Text4, Text4, Text4, Text4 and this happened in order, from left to rightm no random click. In order like x1 x2 x3. Thank u very mutch! I love yur feedback!